# hasChildNodes() of attribute nodes return different results for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, cross-browser

Check this jsfiddle separately in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/9aE2p/1/

Also pasting the same code here:

```
var xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><abc abc_attr="abc_attr_value"><abc_child abc_child_attr="abc_child_attr_value1"/><abc_child abc_child_attr="abc_child_attr_value2"/></abc>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");

var path = 'abc/@abc_attr';

var nodes = xmlDoc.evaluate(path, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var result = nodes.iterateNext();

while (result) {
    var textContent = '<BR>result.textContent: "' + result.textContent + '"';
    var nodeType = '<BR>result.nodeType: "' + result.nodeType + '"';
    var resultHasChildren = '<BR>result.hasChildNodes(): ' + result.hasChildNodes();

    document.write(nodeType);
    document.write(textContent);
    document.write(resultHasChildren);

    result = nodes.iterateNext();
}
```

What I am noticing is that hasChildNodes() returns false for Firefox and true for Chrome.

If a [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) is an attribute node, then in Chrome it has a child node which has the actual value.
But in Firefox, it doesn't have any child node and the value is stored inside attribute node itself.

I am curious to know is there is any documentation on this subtle difference?

I already checked the following documents but couldn't find any such specifics:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.hasChildNodes

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-810594187

Comment: interested one, the Opera agreed with Chrome

Comment: Maybe it has to do with Webkit vs Gecko. Is Opera based on webkit based?

Comment: nope, they have own presto, guess very old one

Comment: Well, I thought we were beyond these subtle differences in modern browsers. Apparently, this subtle difference actually broke some code in my workplace.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Attr Read the comment in the warning box, might have to do with the changes according to DOM4.

Comment: Hey thanks for this info FK82, if you could post it as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: okay it's Mozilla
look at the documentation
...
hasChildNodes()
This method now always returns false.

Comment: Hi bits, I just did. Thanks!

Comment: Mozilla, your browser is bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think you did not understand the situation. FF isn't bad. It turns out that Mozilla is simply being more DOM4 compliant, while Chrome is not there yet. See the accepted answer for more details.

Comment: @bits I thing you did not understand the joke.

Comment: I did not. Well, if it was a joke, never mind then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As just posted in my comment, I believe this has to do with changes to the way attributes are implemented in DOM4 in contrast to previous version.

- [Link to Attr interface documentation on Mozilla Developer Network, MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Attr)

In previous versions the `Attr` interface extended `Node`. This was changed so you cannot use `Node` methods anymore. However, the `name` and `value` properties still exist.

Answer (score 0):

selector

```
var path = 'abc/@abc_attr';
```

returns attribute node (Attr), which is by nature could not have child nodes at all, and there is reason for Mozilla developers (guess) made hasChildNodes() deprecated for attributes.

selector

```
var path = 'abc[@abc_attr]'
```

returns node element (Element)

sample here:

http://jsbin.com/udugug/1

spec link which makes bit light over here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-637646024